# manipular hml desde c#

Tags: html, c#, json

Estoy trabajando en c# .NET core para AWS.
Tengo una plantilla html en la que debo remplazar unos valores de un json. Todo esto mediante codigo c#, hasta ahí todo bien.

El html lo tengo en una varibale como cadena, ya que sera el cuerpo de un correo electrónico.

El problema es cuando en el json viene un arreglo.

```
{
    "nombrecliente": "Alfredo",
    "appaterno": "Villegas",
    "apmaterno": "Machorro",
    "productos": [
        {
            "imagensku1": "",
            "descripcionsku1": "SET DE 32 PZA DADOS C/MATRACA",
            "nosku1": "36000651",
            "existenciassku1": "5",
            "cantidadsku1": "1",
            "importesku1": "88.99"
        },
        {
            "imagensku2": "",
            "descripcionsku2": "SET DE 32 PZA DADOS C/MATRACA",
            "nosku2": "36000651",
            "existenciassku2": "5",
            "cantidadsku2": "1",
            "importesku2": "88.99"
        }
    ],
    "totalventa": "100.25"
}
```

Este arreglo se debe representar en una tabla, pero no se como hacerlo ya que en la platilla yo debería ubicar el renglón en la tabla y replicarlo las veces del arreglo pero no se como hacer eso desde c#.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: como integras el json con el html, usas alguna libreria como ser jquery, o alguna de template, quizas e spor medio de angularjs

Comment: creo que no me hacian falta mas datos para no confundir a los lectores, todo esto se realiza con codigo c# la plantilla la tengo en una cadena y necesito remplazar los valores en esa cadena que tiene el formato html

Answer (score 0):

Usando codigo servidor o sea `c#` puedes ayudarte del engine `Razor` para combinar el html con el json, solo que este no podra usarse como un simple string, sino que debera ser `parseado` a una clase

Entonces el primer paso es obtener esa clase, para eso te ayudas de

http://json2csharp.com/

obteniendo la clase

```
public class Producto
{
    public string imagensku1 { get; set; }
    public string descripcionsku1 { get; set; }
    public string nosku1 { get; set; }
    public string existenciassku1 { get; set; }
    public string cantidadsku1 { get; set; }
    public string importesku1 { get; set; }
    public string imagensku2 { get; set; }
    public string descripcionsku2 { get; set; }
    public string nosku2 { get; set; }
    public string existenciassku2 { get; set; }
    public string cantidadsku2 { get; set; }
    public string importesku2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string nombrecliente { get; set; }
    public string appaterno { get; set; }
    public string apmaterno { get; set; }
    public List<Producto> productos { get; set; }
    public string totalventa { get; set; }
}
```

ese sera tu modelo, el cual deserializas usando `json.net`

```
RootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Teniendo esto puedes usar el engine razor el cual obtienes de nuget

[RazorEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/)

Siendo tan simple como unir todo

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, model);
```

Esto es solo un ejmeplo, en el template pondrias el `mail html template` para unirlo a los datos del `model` de la deserializacion del `json`

Comment: Agradezco tu tiempo Leandro, y me temo que no precisamente es para fron, este es un servicio que enviara un correo mediante lambda de AWS el html es parte del mensaje que irá en el correo entonces no estoy seguro de poder usar Angular.

Comment: pero entonces te has explicado bastante mal, porque s mencionas un html y json es para crear algo visual, no algo que debe combinar fisicamente y generar otro html estatico de respuesta. Lo que tampoco mencionas es con que codigo quieres lograr esto, si sera algo con javascript o c#. Si aclaras este tema editando la pregunta cambio la respuesta, pero deberias quitar el negativo si hago eso

Comment: ahora si, usando codigo servidor para obtener un html estatico en base a un template y el json

Comment: Si, tienes mucho razón Leandro agradezco tus observaciones ya eh editado.

Comment: a que te refieres con que quite el negativo?

Comment: me referia al voto negativo que habian puesto sobre la respuesta, es que hay un tema en stackoverflow con el hecho de eliminar y volver a responder, pero ya estaria

Comment: agradezco tu respuesta, la idea de este servicio que envía correos es que sea genérico osea que podría recibir diferentes json por eso es que no eh creado una entidad para parsear el json ya que en ocasiones el json puede cambiar.

Comment: RazorEngine en de terceros o es de microsoft?

Comment: es una implementacion de terceros pero de libre uso, basado en motor de render Razor que si es de Microsoft